# unrecognized jquery selector with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a markup like this

```
<div id="abc">abc</div>
<div id="def">abc</div>
<div id="xyz">abc</div>
```

and I want to hide/show base on my array value

```
var data = ["abc","def","xyz"];
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
      console.log(val) // abc def xyz
      $("[id=" + val + "]").show(); // doesn't work
      $('#' + val).show() //doesn't work too
    })
```

but I go the following error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression`

Comment: what is data referring to ?

Comment: i am not seeing any error.Check out this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0mdpbvb1/)

Answer (score 0):

are you included JQUERY, before your custom JS?
if yes, should work. Please share more code.

Here your code working...

```js
    var data = ["abc", "def", "xyz"];
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        console.log(val) // abc def xyz
        $("[id=" + val + "]").hide(); // this work
        //$('#' + val).hide()
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="abc">abc</div>
    <div id="def">abc</div>
    <div id="xyz">abc</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see no difference between your code and the snippet in question & if jquery is not included then $ is undefined would have been the first error